# sendKeys() not working for one of my input fileds

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I've two input fields in the form and their source is mentioned below

```
<input class="col8 last right i-f ssn" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please enter valid SSN number" data-val-regex-pattern="^((\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|X{3}-X{2}-X{4}))$" id="SSN" name="SSN" type="text" value="" />

<input class="col8 last right i-f" id="MiddleName" maxlength="15" name="MiddleName" onkeypress="return isAlphabetKey(event)" type="text" value="" />
```

I am trying to send input using the following command in selenium web driver (Firefox)

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='SSN']")).sendKeys("55555");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='MiddleName']")).sendKeys("xyz");
```

for the first field no error is appearing while I run this under TestNG but second field is working fine I've included the page source for both input fields for ease.

Comment: Please re-read your question. Its not clear where the problem lies.

Comment: the source html you links does not contain any element with id='Zip'

Comment: The ID of the first field is "SSN", NOT "Zip"

Comment: When you run across problems like this, it is good practice to first confirm the element is found - or check the ID values as has been mentioned.

Comment: My Bad, I've edited now, but actual problem is sendKeys() not working for SSN field but working for the other one

Answer (score 6):

Possible Solution 1:   Execute javascript call to sendKeys()
As you stated, it is most likely the formatting of the textbox that is not allowing you to sendKeys() to the input box. The reason might just be the way that WebDriver handles putting input into a box. I'd recommend trying javascript to execute a different type of input filling method.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

executor.executeScript("document.getElementById("SSN").value='55555';);
```

Possible Solution 2:   https://github.com/dsheiko/autofill

I don't have a good code snippet that i can show you for utilizing autofill, but the github itself has pretty nice examples.

Possible Solution 3:   Remove the formatting attribute of the input tag, then use sendKeys()

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByID('SSN'[0].removeAttribute('data-val-regex-pattern');");
    WebElement input= driver.findElement(By.id("SSN"));
    input.clear();
    input.sendKeys("55555");
```

Comment: If you have access to the page's html source code, maybe test around with getting rid of that attribute of the tag just for experimentation. Also, I found another possible solution for you, so let me edit my answer to add that on as well.

Comment: also, have you tried any other actions on the webelement such as clicking, getAttribute(), etc?

Comment: I don't have access to change the html but i tried getAttribute() its working fine I don't know what is the problem out there

Comment: I'd have to assume that the formatted text box is the problem. Sendkeys() for java selenium webdriver might not work. I'll throw a code snippet for a javascript call using webdriver in my answer. See if that works.

Answer (score 2):

If there is any implementation of JQuery on a text field sendKey() for selenium will not work you have to use the following code snippet

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('field_id').value = 'field_val';");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the attribute that formats the input tag. Then you can just use SendKeys().